# How to get Y coordinate of item on listview

Tags: android, listview, coordinate

The goal of my code is to move a ImageView to the center of the clicked item to "highlight" it on some way. For this, I'm trying to get the Y coordinate of the clicked item of a listview.
My code is:

```
private OnItemClickListener listview_auto_listener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
            long arg3) {

        int[] coords = new int[2];

        view.getLocationOnScreen(coords);

        // We need just the top coordinate
        int top = coords[1];
        // And bottom

        moveSelectedCar(top);

    }
};
```

where moveSelectedCar is:

```
private void moveSelectedCar(int new_y) {

    TranslateAnimation _tAnim = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, last_y, new_y);

    _tAnim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    _tAnim.setDuration(800);
    _tAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    _tAnim.setFillEnabled(true);

    img_selected_car.startAnimation(_tAnim);

    last_y = new_y;

}
```

The problem is that this doesn't return the center of the clicked item.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't return to the center of the clicked item? What does the Animation code you published do?

Comment: The Animation code has to center the ImageView to the center of the clicked row. The problem is to find that center....i tried to do it on the code above. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I've solved the problem!

```
private OnItemClickListener listview_auto_listener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
            long arg3) {

        int new_top = view.getTop() + view.getRight();
        int view_height = view.getHeight();

        moveSelectedCar(new_top - view_height);

    }
};
```

> I Hope this helps somebody!